# Set webapp on iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications

I want to replicate the functionality that shows on map.google.com or m.grooveshark.com for example that when you access the web app on the default browser it asks you as a user if you want to set this webapp on your "desktop". ¿How do I do that on both platform?.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try the [Mobile Bookmark Bubble](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/wiki/Mobile-Bookmark-Bubble) javascript library.

> The Mobile Bookmark Bubble is a JavaScript library that adds a promo bubble to the bottom of your mobile web application, inviting users to bookmark the app to their device's home screen.
>
> There are two new versions of implementation, one supports Mobile Safari only, while the other supports Mobile Safari, Android, Blackberry touch smartphones and Playbook.